# Angular argument X is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi there I have an error when entering route #/view1: Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'homeApp.HomeCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

```
// homeController.js

'use strict';

angular.module('homeApp').controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    // object to hold all the data for the new comment form
    $scope.commentData = {};

    // loading variable to show the spinning loading icon
    $scope.loading = true;
}]);
```

main file:

```
// app.js
'use strict';

angular.module('homeApp', []);

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'homeApp']).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/view1', {
templateUrl: 'partials/login.html', 
controller: 'homeApp.HomeCtrl'
});

$routeProvider.when('/view2', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html', controller: 'MyCtrl2'});
}]);
```

I am loading files in this order: app.js, homeController.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to include the modules name into the controller-property of the route. Just do

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'homeApp']).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/login.html', 
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    });
```

Comment: But if I delete from app.js angular.module['homeApp', []); I have got: Module 'homeApp' is not available!

Comment: I didnt say you should delete `angular.module['homeApp', [])`. Just change the controller-property of the router-config, you can leave the rest of your app.js in place like it was ;)

Comment: I still don't see difference

Comment: Whoops haha. I just copied without doing the actual work. Sorry. I edited the snippet above, this should work now ;)